Problem on proving $L^p_T(\dot{H}^{s+\frac{2}{p}})$ estimate of a heat flow
I met a problem when reading Bahouri, Chemin & Danchin's book Fourier Analysis and Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations. On page 210 the authors give the following lemma:
Lemma 5.10. Let $v$ be the solution in $\mathcal{C}([0,T];\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d))$ of the Cauchy problem
$$
\begin{cases}
\partial_tv-\nu\Delta v=f\\
v|_{t=0}=v_0
\end{cases}
$$
with $f$ in $L^2([0,T];\dot{H}^{s-1})$ and $v_0$ in $\dot{H}^s(\mathbb{R}^d).$ Then,
$$
v\in\biggl(\bigcap_{p=2}^{\infty}L^p([0,T];\dot{H}^{s+\frac{2}{p}})\biggr)\cap\mathcal{C}([0,T];\dot{H}^s).
$$
Moreover, we have the following estimates:
$$
\|v(t)\|_{\dot{H}^s}^2+2\nu\int_0^t\|\nabla v(t')\|_{\dot{H}^s}^2dt'=\|v_0\|_{\dot{H}^s}^2+2\int_0^t\langle f(t'),v(t')\rangle_sdt',
$$
$$
\biggl(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|\xi|^{2s}\Bigl(\sup_{0\le t'\le t}|\widehat{v}(t',\xi)|\Bigr)^2d\xi\biggr)^{\frac{1}{2}}\le\|v_0\|_{\dot{H}^s}+\frac{1}{(2\nu)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\|f\|_{L_T^2(\dot{H}^{s-1})},
$$
$$
\|v(t)\|_{L^p_T(\dot{H}^{s+\frac{2}{p}})}\le\frac{1}{\nu^{\frac{1}{p}}}\biggl(\|v_0\|_{\dot{H}^s}+\frac{1}{\nu^{\frac{1}{2}}}\|f\|_{L_T^2(\dot{H}^{s-1})}\biggr)
$$
with $\langle a,b\rangle_s:=\int|\xi|^{2s}\widehat{a}(\xi)\overline{\widehat{b}(\xi)}d\xi$.
My problem is on proving the third inequality, i.e. the $L_T^p(\dot{H}^{s-1})$ estimate of $v(t)$. The authors say it "follows by interpolation", but I'm confused on which interpolation theorem should I use? And which two spaces will be endpoints of interpolation? I guess one endpoint must be $L_T^{\infty}(\dot{H}^s)$(i.e. the second inequality), but what's the other one? I've tried to prove $v\in L^2([0,T];\dot{H}^{s+1})$ but failed: I don't know how to estimate $\|v(t)\|_{\dot{H}^{s+1}}$ since $v_0$ is only in $\dot{H}^s$. Even if regarding $L_T^2(\dot{H}^{s+1})$ as the other endpoint, I think there should appear some exponent on $\|v_0\|_{\dot{H}^s}+\frac{1}{\nu^{\frac{1}{2}}}\|f\|_{L_T^2(\dot{H}^{s-1})}$.

I think I've figured out this problem so I'll try to answer myself.
In general, the endpoints are indeed $L^{\infty}_T(\dot{H}^s)$ and $L^2_T(\dot{H}^{s+1})$, so we need to first show $v\in L^2_T(\dot{H}^{s+1})$. By the energy equality (i.e. the first estimate) we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
2\nu\int_0^t\|\nabla v(t')\|_{\dot{H}^s}^2dt'&=\|v_0\|_{\dot{H}^s}^2+2\int_0^t\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|\xi|^{s-1}\widehat{f}(t',\xi)\cdot|\xi|^{s+1}\widehat{v}(t',-\xi)dt'\\
&\le\|v_0\|_{\dot{H}^s}^2+2\int_0^t\frac{1}{\nu^{\frac{1}{2}}}\|f(t')\|_{\dot{H}^{s-1}}\cdot\nu^{\frac{1}{2}}\|v(t')\|_{\dot{H}^{s+1}}dt'\\
&\le\|v_0\|_{\dot{H}^s}^2+\frac{1}{\nu}\int_0^t\|f(t')\|_{\dot{H}^{s-1}}^2dt'+\nu\int_0^t\|v(t')\|_{\dot{H}^{s+1}}^2dt'
\end{aligned}
$$
while the first inequality above used Holder's inequality. Thus for $t\in[0,T]$ we have
$$
\|v\|_{L^2([0,t];\dot{H}^{s+1})}^2\le\frac{1}{\nu}\biggl(\|v_0\|_{\dot{H}^s}+\frac{1}{\nu^{\frac{1}{2}}}\|f\|_{L^2([0,t];\dot{H}^{s-1})}\biggr)^2.
$$
In particular it tells that $v\in L^2([0,T];\dot{H}^{s+1})$. Now for $p\in(2,\infty)$ we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|v\|_{L^p([0,T];\dot{H}^{s+\frac{2}{p}})}=&\biggl[\int_0^T\biggl(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|\xi|^{2s+\frac{4}{p}}|\widehat{v}|^2d\xi\biggr)^{\frac{p}{2}}dt\biggr]^{\frac{1}{p}}\\
=&\biggl[\int_0^T\biggl(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}(|\xi|^{2(s+1)}|\widehat{v}|^2)^{\frac{2}{p}}(|\xi|^{2s}|\widehat{v}|^2)^{1-\frac{2}{p}}d\xi\biggr)^{\frac{p}{2}}dt\biggr]^{\frac{1}{p}}\\
\le&\biggl[\int_0^T\biggl(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}(|\xi|^{2(s+1)}|\widehat{v}|^2)^{\frac{2}{p}\cdot\frac{p}{2}}d\xi\biggr)^{\frac{2}{p}\cdot\frac{p}{2}}\biggl(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}(|\xi|^{2s}|\widehat{v}|^2)^{(1-\frac{2}{p})\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{p}}}d\xi\biggr)^{(1-\frac{2}{p})\cdot\frac{p}{2}}dt\biggr]^{\frac{1}{p}}\\
=&\biggl[\int_0^T\|v\|_{\dot{H}^{s+1}}^2\|v\|_{\dot{H}^s}^{p-2}dt\biggr]^{\frac{1}{p}}\le\|v\|_{L^{\infty}([0,T];\dot{H}^s)}^{1-\frac{2}{p}}\|v\|_{L^2([0,T];\dot{H}^{s+1})}^\frac{2}{p}\\
\le&\biggl(\|v_0\|_{\dot{H}^s}+\frac{1}{(2\nu)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\|f\|_{L^2([0,T];\dot{H}^{s-1})}\biggr)^{1-\frac{2}{p}}\frac{1}{\nu^{\frac{1}{p}}}\biggl(\|v_0\|_{\dot{H}^s}+\frac{1}{\nu^{\frac{1}{2}}}\|f\|_{L^2([0,T];\dot{H}^{s-1})}\biggr)^{\frac{2}{p}}\\
\le&\frac{1}{\nu^{\frac{1}{p}}}\biggl(\|v_0\|_{\dot{H}^s}+\frac{1}{\nu^{\frac{1}{2}}}\|f\|_{L^2([0,T];\dot{H}^{s-1})}\biggr).
\end{aligned}
$$
